I am trying to run GeckoDriver but getting error in last line
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Set up the WebDriver for Firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')  # Replace with the correct path

In line 7 how do I put the path so that I don't get an error? It seems like my setup is wrong somewhere, and it's showing me this error:
File "C:\Users\Farhan\Desktop\fox.py", line 7
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\Users\Farhan\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.35.0-win-aarch64\drivers\geckodriver.exe')  # Replace with the correct path
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

How can I repair this setup of GeckoDriver?
I downloaded GeckoDriver and put the path in the code after installing Selenium, but it's not working.

This question is similar to: "Unicode Error 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes..." when writing Windows file paths. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Or -  How should I write a Windows path in a Python string literal?

By the way, thanks for providing code! But make sure your samples always represent a [mre]. The code you've provided doesn't reproduce your problem because you've altered the executable path, and it includes some unused imports.
